# Question about MIDI library

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial, midi

I'm trying to replace this code with something that uses the Arduino MIDI library:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define rxPin 2
#define txPin 1

SoftwareSerial midiSerial (rxPin,txPin);

void setup() {
  midiSerial.begin(31250); }

while ( midiSerial.available()) {
    incomingCommand = midiSerial.read();
    incomingNote = midiSerial.read();
    incomingVelocity = midiSerial.read()*8.05511811024; 
  if (incomingVelocity <=1023) {
    midiSerial.write(incomingCommand);
    midiSerial.write(incomingNote);
    midiSerial.write(incomingVelocity); } }
```

Here's what I came up with:

```
#include <MIDI.h> // MIDI Output
MIDI_CREATE_DEFAULT_INSTANCE();

byte MIDIChannel;
byte programByte1;
byte controlByte1;
byte controlByte2;

void setup() {
  MIDI.begin();
}

void loop() {
 if (MIDI.read()) switch (MIDI.getType()) {
      MIDIChannel = MIDI.getChannel();
    case midi::ProgramChange:
      programByte1 = MIDI.getData1();
      break;
    case midi::ControlChange:
      controlByte1 = MIDI.getData1();
      controlByte2 = MIDI.getData2();
      break; 
    default: break; 
    }
}
```

Does that look correct? It doesn't function as smoothly as the version that uses SoftwareSerial

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: "Does that look correct?" It doesn't seem to take in any MIDI input data

Comment: how do you know this?

Comment: I've updated the code above and added the rest of the commands to my switch-case setup, so I'll keep searching for the data I'm looking for, which is specifically the 'command' data. Should be straightforward with some digging

Comment: The first code transmits MIDI data, and the second receives it, so they are not having the same functionality, actually opposite functionality. Also, do not use software serial for MIDI. It works ok for single notes, but if you start using e.g. CC data, you sometimes miss data, which is very problematic when these are MIDI Note Off messages.

Comment: The second piece of code doesn't do anything useful. I think it will not even compile (instruction after switch without case)